# how to process all column in my dataframe and produce a new column

Tags: apache-spark, row, rdd, apache-spark-sql

This is a example

i have a dataframe

```
+---+---------+----+------------+-----+
| id|     name| age|   describle|value|
+---+---------+----+------------+-----+
|  0|hansongbo|null| he is great|   11|
|  1|   marong|  23|        null| null|
|  2|hansongbo|  34|        null| null|
|  3|   marong|  34|she love han|   12|
+---+---------+----+------------+-----+
```

Now i want to compute the length of all string columns,And the result is

```
 +---+---------+----+------------+-----+------+
| id|     name| age|   describle|value|length|
+---+---------+----+------------+-----+------+
|  0|hansongbo|null| he is great|   11|   20 |
|  1|   marong|  23|        null| null|   6  |
|  2|hansongbo|  34|        null| null|   9  |
|  3|   marong|  34|she love han|   12|   18 |
+---+---------+----+------------+-----+------+
```

How can i make it ,hope your help,thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO ! What have you tried so far ? This is really a very low quality question. Try to show that you made some effort so we'll be willing to help!

Answer (score 0):

let's name the dataframe A.

```
A.registerTempTable("tableA")
b = sqlContext.sql("select `id`,`name`,age,describle,value,length(`name`)+length(`describle`) as `length` from tableA")
```